# How to remove two question mark diamond shaped symbols before text in Github file

Tags: git, powershell, github, unix

I want to add a line of text to a file using git. I did like below. However the test appears with two symbols in front of it in Github (shown below). How do I get rid of these symbols?

```
echo "my text" > file_name
```

[image]

I tried using double quotation and combination of single and double quotation. I don't want there to be those symbols.

Comment: What IDE are you using to add the line?

Comment: I am using the powershell terminal.

Comment: In PowerShell, **`>`** is an effective alias of the **`Out-File`** cmdlet, whose default output character encoding in **Windows PowerShell** is **"Unicode" (UTF-16LE)**; in **PowerShell (Core) 7+**, it is **BOM-less UTF8**. To control the character encoding, call `Out-File` or, for text input, `Set-Content` with the **`-Encoding` parameter**.

Comment: In _Windows PowerShell_, `-Encoding utf8` invariably creates a UTF-8 file _with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)_; to avoid that, you'll either have to use `New-Item -Force -Value` (e.g, ``New-Item -Force out.txt -Value "café`n"``) or  call a .NET API directly (e.g., ``[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("$PWD/out.txt", "café`n")``. In _PowerShell (Core) 7+_, fortunately, BOM-less UTF-8 is the consistent _default_ across all cmdlets (use `-Encoding utf8bom` to create one).